# Downgrade database with liquibase - Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, liquibase

I have small project written in Spring. For database migration and seeds I use liquibase.

After some time I have request to downgrade my database to previous version. Is this possible to do with liquibase and what workflow do you recommend? I can do that with packaging new war file and run some pure sql scripts but that is not a good way for me. I just want to do that with liquibase - maybe some rollback to previous version.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Liquibase can not simply (automatically) rollback already existent updates. Only thing you could do - write additional changesets, where you will manually describe needed changes in the DB, which will return structure to needed state.

You can also describe [rollback actions](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html) in advance in order to make this process more nice, it is can be done via `rollback` section in each changeset.

Answer (score 1):

remember that db rollback is not something that is in general feasible. for example in v1 you have a column A full of data (to make discussion easier: with not null constrain and without a default value). in v2 you delete column A. how do you want to automatically perform rollback / downgrade?

i suggest to add another migration that will migrate your db to state v3 that looks exactly like / similar to v1. inside this migration you can handle all the missing data etc